# Overriding IEquatable<T> when T is an interface and hashcodes are different between derived types

Tags: c#, .net, interface, gethashcode, iequatable

I have `A` and `B` classes both implementing interface `I`.

```
public interface I
{
    int SomeInt { get; }
    bool SomeBool { get; }
    float SomeFloat { get; }
}


public class A : I
{
    public int SomeInt { get; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; }
    public float SomeFloat { get; }

    private readonly string _someARelatedStuff;
    // Rest of class...
}

public class B : I
{
    public int SomeInt { get; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; }
    public float SomeFloat { get; }

    private string readonly _someBRelatedStuff;
    private double readonly _someOtherBRelatedStuff;
    // Rest of class...
}
```

Sometimes I want to test equality between `A` and `B` (usually when comparing lists of `A` and lists of `B`) based on the equality of their `I` properties (`SomeInt`, `SomeBool`, `SomeFloat`), so I implemented `IEquatable<I>` on both and I compare them based on their shared `I` properties values.

The problem is that I already have an implementation for `GetHashCode()` on both A and B that produces different hashes because I'm taking into account additional members.

`B` does not depend on `A` so I use interface `I` to compare them and it has a list of properties with getters.

I read [in a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6899079/6104191) that:

> If you are implementing a class, you should always make sure that two equal objects have the same hashcode.

So does that mean that everytime a class `A` want to be implement interface `I`, and I want to be able to compare instances that implement `I`, I have to make sure the hashcode is calculated in the same way for all instances of `I` and only use `I` properties?

I do feel like I'm not intended to implement `IEquatable<T>` when T is an interface, but my alternatives are:

1. Using regular inheritance with a base class - I rather avoid inheritance when possible, and this solution won't work if B needs to derive from some framework `C` class because of single inheritance
2. Implement equality checks between `A` and `B` with a method on either `A` or `B` - will create code duplication
3. Have an equality check method between `I` instances defined in `I` - sounds like the best option

Are there any options that I'm missing?

Comment: it depends on the intent and what does it equality means between two objects in that context.

Comment: If A and B are different (have different properties) then I don't see why you would ever try to compare them for equality. A should be compared to other A's and B should be compared to other B's. Your question seems to be how to compare apples(class A) to oranges(class B) which both implement Interface (Fruit).

Comment: You could write an implementation of [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) for your interface and use that to compare instances. This is similar to option (3) in your question.  (This is usually used with collection classes that accept an `IEqualityComparer` to override the normal equality comparison for the collection element type.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson That sounds like a better solution than what I have in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanWilson
@EhsanSajjad
As I said in the question - I want to compare a list of `A` and a list of `B` for their `I` derived properties equality. IEquatable<I>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making the a `IEqualityComparer<>` class to compare the common values.

<sub>I have renamed the interface to `ICommon` for readability</sub>

```
public interface ICommon
{
    int SomeInt { get; }
    bool SomeBool { get; }
    float SomeFloat { get; }
}

public class CommonComparer : IEqualityComparer<ICommon>
{
    public bool Equals(ICommon x, ICommon y)
    {
        return x.SomeInt.Equals(y.SomeInt)
            && x.SomeBool.Equals(y.SomeBool)
            && x.SomeFloat.Equals(y.SomeFloat);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ICommon obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = -1817952719;
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + obj.SomeInt.GetHashCode();
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + obj.SomeBool.GetHashCode();
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + obj.SomeFloat.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }
}
```

and the program can distinguish between the equal items on two lists.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listA = new List<A>
        {
            new A(1001, true, 1.001f, "A1"),
            new A(1002, true, 1.002f, "A2"),
            new A(1003, false, 1.003f, "A1"),
            new A(1004, false, 1.004f, "A4")
        };

        var listB = new List<B>
        {
            new B(1001, true, 1.001f, "B1", 2.5),
            new B(1002, false, 1.002f, "B2", 2.8),
            new B(1003, true, 1.003f, "B3", 2.9),
            new B(1004, false, 1.004f, "B4", 2.9)
        };

        var common = Enumerable.Intersect(listA, listB, new CommonComparer()).OfType<ICommon>();


        Console.WriteLine($"{"SomeInt",-8} {"Bool",-6} {"SomeFloat",-10}");
        foreach (var item in common)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.SomeInt,-8} {item.SomeBool,-6} {item.SomeFloat,-10}");
        }
        //SomeInt  Bool   SomeFloat
        //1001     True   1.001
        //1004     False  1.004

    }
}
```

and the rest of the code definitions

```
public class A : ICommon, IEquatable<A>
{
    static readonly CommonComparer comparer = new CommonComparer();

    public int SomeInt { get; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; }
    public float SomeFloat { get; }

    private readonly string _someARelatedStuff;
    // Rest of class...
    public A(ICommon other, string someARelatedStuff)
        : this(other.SomeInt, other.SomeBool, other.SomeFloat, someARelatedStuff)
    { }
    public A(int someInt, bool someBool, float someFloat, string someARelatedStuff)
    {
        this.SomeInt = someInt;
        this.SomeBool = someBool;
        this.SomeFloat = someFloat;
        this._someARelatedStuff = someARelatedStuff;
    }

    public override string ToString() => _someARelatedStuff;

    #region IEquatable Members
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is A other)
        {
            return Equals(other);
        }
        return false;
    }


    public virtual bool Equals(A other)
    {
        return comparer.Equals(this, other)
            && _someARelatedStuff.Equals(other._someARelatedStuff);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = comparer.GetHashCode(this);
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + _someARelatedStuff.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}

public class B : ICommon, IEquatable<B>
{
    static readonly CommonComparer comparer = new CommonComparer();

    public int SomeInt { get; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; }
    public float SomeFloat { get; }

    readonly string _someBRelatedStuff;
    readonly double _someOtherBRelatedStuff;
    // Rest of class...

    public B(ICommon other, string someBRelatedStuff, double someOtherBRelatedStuff)
        : this(other.SomeInt, other.SomeBool, other.SomeFloat, someBRelatedStuff, someOtherBRelatedStuff)
    { }
    public B(int someInt, bool someBool, float someFloat, string someBRelatedStuff, double someOtherBRelatedStuff)
    {
        this.SomeInt = someInt;
        this.SomeBool = someBool;
        this.SomeFloat = someFloat;
        this._someBRelatedStuff = someBRelatedStuff;
        this._someOtherBRelatedStuff = someOtherBRelatedStuff;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{_someBRelatedStuff}, {_someOtherBRelatedStuff.ToString("g4")}";

    #region IEquatable Members

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is B other)
        {
            return Equals(other);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(B other)
    {
        return comparer.Equals(this, other)
            && _someBRelatedStuff.Equals(other._someBRelatedStuff)
            && _someOtherBRelatedStuff.Equals(other._someOtherBRelatedStuff);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = comparer.GetHashCode(this);
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + _someBRelatedStuff.GetHashCode();
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + _someOtherBRelatedStuff.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```